# iOS Push notifications token change - after token update there is 2 min delay before Salesforce notes can be sent

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

After token has changed app is calling:

```
  [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setDeviceToken:deviceToken];
```

After that app is moved to background and I go on and start sending some push notifications from Salesforce web app. Only notes that are sent 2 min after token update are arriving on device which had its token changed and which called Salesforce SDK and notified about token change.

Is this documented somewhere - how long does it take for Salesforce to handle "token changed" event? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vale4674, I don't believe the "system" is documented enough to describe the timeline of what happens (yet - we have an documentation ticket in our system for just this).

Generally speaking, when the SDK gets a "registration" change (in this case deviceToken, but could also be contactKey, tags, attributes, etc.) the SDK will send that change (and any others) after 60s (to reduce usage impact). Once the server receives that registration data, it should be picked up from the processing queue after one minute.

If all things are in place, the two minutes you found is the right timeline.

We have seen cases where under heavy loads the system may take up to 15 minutes to fully process a registration, but that would be an extreme case.

Thanks for the feedback - we'll keep at the documentation improvements.

Brian Criscuolo

Senior Mobile Engineer & Product Owner, MobilePush SDK